# How to set an order for association array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I' ve got a controller

```
class Api::V1::QuestionsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  authorize_resource  
  before_action :set_question, only:[:show] 



  api :GET, '/questions/id', 'This renders question by id'
  def show
    render json:@question
  end
```

and a serializer

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body, :created_at, :updated_at, :short_title
  has_many :answers
  has_many :comments
  has_many :attachments

  def short_title
    object.title.truncate(10)
  end
end
```

Here is a part of test

```
context 'answers' do
    it 'included in question object' do
      expect(response.body).to have_json_size(2).at_path("answers")
    end        

    %w(id body created_at updated_at).each do |attr|
      it "contains #{attr}" do 
      #NO UNDERSTANDING AT ALL!!!!!         
        expect(response.body).to be_json_eql(answers[0].send(attr.to_sym).to_json).at_path("answers/1/#{attr}")
      end
    end
  end
```

The thing is that this test passes, so obviously (for unknown reasons for me) the scope differs. I am new to rails, could anybody tell me how could I set a default scope to normalize my responds, also I have to admit that In my app I have a similar not api controller  and there are no problems with that scope.

Comment: looks like this helped   def comments
    object.comments.order(updated_at: :asc)
  end

Answer (score 0):

Yep this is the way. I should only set order in serializer

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body, :created_at, :updated_at, :short_title
  has_many :answers
  has_many :comments
  has_many :attachments

  def comments
    object.comments.order(updated_at: :asc)
  end

  def answers
    object.answers.order(updated_at: :asc)
  end

  def attachments
    object.attachments.order(updated_at: :asc)
  end

  def short_title
    object.title.truncate(10)
  end
end
```